# Two HTTP requests use different Hibernate Sessions, but same Database session

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, session

In my web application I'm using Hibernate to call a stored procedure in an Oracle Database.

The application connects as one schema, and sets the client identifier to determine which user has made the request. The stored proc updates the client identifier like this

```
SYS.DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER('<userId>');
```

Before each HTTP request the request handling thread will get a Hibernate session and call the stored procedure like this:

```
String SET_CONTEXT_SQL = "call my_stored_proc(:userId)";

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(SET_CONTEXT_SQL);
query.setParameter("userId", userId);

query.executeUpdate();
```

After the request it will clear the identifier.

It appears that two seperate threads, with two different session objects (I checked with session.hashCode()), will update the same database session's CLIENT_IDENTIFER.

I can see in the session table using breakpoints and checking the session table at various times during request handling, like so:

```
SELECT SID, CLIENT_IDENTIFIER FROM v$session WHERE USERNAME='<schema>';
```

This is a problem one user sends a request before another user's request handling is complete.

I've been looking really hard and I can't seem to find what's causing this behaviour. Has anyone had something like this happen before? Can someone explain how Hibernate Sessions relate to database sessions?

Comment: How/where do you call this (a `Filter`) and how do you obtain the `userId`? Could you post the full code for the `Filter`(?).

Comment: Is the same hibernate session active for the entire request? Maybe you are crossing transaction boundaries. Also note that the database set_indentifier is linked to your connection from your connection pool - you need to make sure that the same connection is used throughout your request thread.